# Is there a better code structure for Google Maps Theming?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop

I'm creating a Google Maps Js snippet where user can choose color from HTML via `data-color`. I have created several color themes. But when added styles for all theme, it looks very lengthy and looks odd. Is there any way I can reduce the code structure to one? Can I wrote For loop for this?

Here is the messy code.

```
    /* Map's style */
    var red1 = "#fd685b",
        red2 = "#fe8e84",
        orange1 = "#fa6f57",
        orange2 = "#fb9381",
        yellow1 = "#fecd5e",
        yellow2 = "#fedc8f",
        green1 = "#4eae49",
        green2 = "#73c16f",
        mint1 = "#4fcead",
        mint2 = "#7bdac2",
        aqua1 = "#4FC1E9",
        aqua2 = "#73d2f4",
        blue1 = "#5D9CEC",
        blue2 = "#86b5f1",
        purple1 = "#ab94e9",
        purple2 = "#c0afef",
        pink1 = "#ea89bf",
        pink2 = "#efa7cf",
        white1 = "#E6E9ED",
        white2 = "#F5F7FA",
        grey1 = "#AAB2BD",
        grey2 = "#CCD1D9",
        darkgrey1 = "#434A54",
        darkgrey2 = "#5f656d";

    if ($map_color == 'red') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": red1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": red2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = red1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'orange') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": orange1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": orange2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = orange1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'yellow') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": yellow1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": yellow2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = yellow1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'green') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": green1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": green2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = green1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'mint') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": mint1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": mint2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = mint1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'aqua') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": aqua1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": aqua2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = aqua1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'blue') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": blue1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": blue2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = blue1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'purple') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": purple1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": purple2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = purple1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'pink') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": pink1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": pink2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = pink1;

    }
    if ($map_color == 'white') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": white1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": white2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = '#333';

    }
    if ($map_color == 'grey') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": grey1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": grey2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = '#333';

    }
    if ($map_color == 'dark-grey') {

        var styles = [{
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": darkgrey1
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": darkgrey2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = '#333';

    }
    if ($map_color == 'invert') {

        var styles = [{
                "stylers": [{
                    "invert_lightness": "true"
                }, {
                    "hue": "0xffbb00"
                }, {
                    "saturation": "-100"
                }, {
                    "lightness": "15"
                }]
            }],
            textcolor = '#333';

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by adding the colors in an object. That said, as far as I know you must do that in this way, unless you make your own class and own prototypes to make it faster and reusable.

Comment: @briosheje I'm also finding another way. Its assigning color values like this. `"stylers": [{
                    "color":  $map_color + '1'
                }]` where in color: the mapcolor + 1 should actually returns the value of green1 if selected. But its not working. Anything we can do in this case?

Comment: @briosheje got working that with eval() but I'm sticking with Object method, Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be probably be easiest to create an object that you can access dynamically using your `$map_color` variable, rather than using a bunch of `else if` statements. For example:

```
/* Map's style */
var colors = {
    red1: "#fd685b",
    red2: "#fe8e84",
    orange1: "#fa6f57",
    orange2: "#fb9381",
    yellow1: "#fecd5e",
    yellow2: "#fedc8f",
    green1: "#4eae49",
    green2: "#73c16f",
    mint1: "#4fcead",
    mint2: "#7bdac2",
    aqua1: "#4FC1E9",
    aqua2: "#73d2f4",
    blue1: "#5D9CEC",
    blue2: "#86b5f1",
    purple1: "#ab94e9",
    purple2: "#c0afef",
    pink1: "#ea89bf",
    pink2: "#efa7cf",
    white1: "#E6E9ED",
    white2: "#F5F7FA",
    grey1: "#AAB2BD",
    grey2: "#CCD1D9",
    darkgrey1: "#434A54",
    darkgrey2: "#5f656d"
};

if ($map_color == 'invert') {

    var styles = [{
            "stylers": [{
                "invert_lightness": "true"
            }, {
                "hue": "0xffbb00"
            }, {
                "saturation": "-100"
            }, {
                "lightness": "15"
            }]
        }],
        textcolor = '#333';

} else {
    var styles = [{
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": colors[$map_color + "1"]
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
       }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape.natural",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": colors[$map_color + "2"]
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }],
    textcolor = colors[$map_color + "1"];
};
```

Comment: This works great.. Instead of object I also tried `eval()` method that also worked.  But I'm sticking to object method. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would put all of the themes in an object like this.

```
var themes = {
    red: {
        styles: [{
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": red1
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape.natural",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": red2
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }],
        textcolor: red1
    },
    ...
};
```

Then access a theme like this.

```
var theme = themes[$map_color] // Contains the theme's `styles` and `textcolor`

theme.styles // Get theme's styles
theme.textcolor // Get theme's text color
```